# android wear notification action button background color

Tags: notifications, action, wear-os

I want to change the action button bg blue color to green color, what method can I use? blue color should be default color of wear action button.

```
Notification.WearableExtender extender = new Notification.WearableExtender();
        extender.addAction(new Action(R.drawable.reply, context.getString(R.string.reply_message_btn), pendingReplyMessageIntent));
        extender.addAction(new Action(R.drawable.ignore, context.getString(R.string.not_to_disturb), pendingIgnoreTalkerIntent));
        extender.addAction(new Action(R.drawable.open_phone, context.getString(R.string.open_on_phone), pendingOpenPhoneIntent));
        notificationBuilder.extend(extender);
```

Comment: Hey, Do u find any way to change the action button color?

Comment: no, i can not find any api to do this

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible - notification actions always have the default blue background.